# Object doesn't act accordingly while moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm working on this tank game where you move a tank using the keyboard input and aiming its turret using the mouse input.

For the tank movement I use this code in the update method:

```
x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;

transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
```

But I get results similar to this video (even when locking the rotation of the axes):
https://streamable.com/tm33b

Is there anyway to prevent such irritability with the movement of the tank, also is there anyway to attach both the body and the turret of the tank while making each rotate independently, also the tank to climb the terrain appropriately.

I'm a beginner to unity, I'm sorry if my questions were obvious or easy. I will be so thankful if I get any direct solution to this.

Comment: Put them both under a game object, so you move the parent game object, and can rotate the whole tank, but can also rotate the turret independantly

Comment: Both are under one tank parent object, but still act weird

Comment: I cant watch the video you linked, and you hadnt mentioned that they were parented.   So  much depends on what you setup, for example the tank moving with the angles of the terrain if you leave physics to it, it should in part do that naturually, but you arent using force and rigid bodys but in essense teleporting your object between places each itteration.

Answer (score 0):

Note that both [Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) and [Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) have a last optional parameter `Space relativeTo = Space.Self`. This means by default always `Space.Self` is used:

> If *relativeTo* is left out or set to `Space.Self` the movement is applied relative to the transform's local axes. (the x, y and z axes shown when selecting the object inside the Scene View.) If *relativeTo* is `Space.World` the movement is applied relative to the world coordinate system.

Your tank opject starts "flying" and "tilting" because you rotate and translate in its own local coordinates instead of world coordinates. You should instead use

```
transform.Rotate(0, x, 0, Space.World);
transform.Translate(0, 0, z, Space.World);
```

to perform the translate and rotate in workd space.